# The equivalent of 'quantum numbers' for a mathematical problem

Tags: terminology, computational-mathematics

I'm working on a mathematical problem and I created an algorithm that will generate a solution depending on the specification of a few integers $m, n, \lambda \in \mathbb{N}$. Each solution is uniquely defined by these parameters and I'm looking for a term to use, when referring to a particular solution via these parameters.

I'm not a native speaker and I struggle to find a proper name. 'Generating set' and 'quantum numbers' are clearly understood by everyone involved, but I wonder whether there are better choices.

Thank you very much.

Comment: "Parameters" seems fine to me.

Comment: There are a lot of other (dependent) parameters also, thus I wanted to be a little bit more specific.

Comment: "Quantum numbers" is catchy.